# Match html tags in python

Tags: python, xml, regex, xpath

I'm writing a python snippet to fix the casing of titles in HTML code. So far, I've come up with this code:

```
pattern = re.compile("<h1>(.*)</h1>|<h2>(.*)</h2>|<h3>(.*)</h3>|<h4>(.*)</h4>|<h5>(.*)</h5>|<h6>(.*)</h6>")

def replace(m):
    contents = m.group(1)
    replacement = contents[0] + contents[1:].lower()
    return replacement
```

Then, given a `line`, the transformation I use is `line = pattern.sub(replace, line)`.

This doesn't work, because `m.group(1)` is always `None`, whereas I'd like it to be the match corresponding to any of the clauses in my regex. Since patterns can't share a name in python, I'm somewhat at a loss.

An obvious solution is to group all the patterns which I used, but then `<h1>bla</h2>` would be recognized. That's not good, since `<h1><a href="...">Bla</a></h1> <h2>Bla</h2>` should yield two matches (`<a href="...">Bla</a>`, and `<a href="...">Bla</a>`)

Ideas?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a single XPath expression that selects exactly all the text nodes that you need to capitalize. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand you just want to capitalize all of the headings. You can use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) which would make this fairly painless:

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.parse(your_html)
for i in range(1,7):
    for h in doc.xpath('//h%d' % i):
        h.text = h.text.capitalize()

print lxml.html.tostring(doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care about that? HTML tags are not case sensitive. If you need a *proper* solution than you use a tool like BeautifulSoup. Parsing HTML using regular expressions is nonsense and never ever recommendable (discussed often enough).

Comment: What do you mean? I never mentioned case sensitivity in the tag, but in the argument. I'm transforming `<h2>YELLING</h2>` to `<h2>Yelling</h2>`, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and all the tons of comments and answers to it. :-)

Use

- [lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) or
- [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

to parse html.

Answer (score 1):

**The following XPath expression selects all the wanted text nodes**:

```
//*[starts-with(name(),'h') 
  and 
   substring(name(),2) >= 1 
  and not(substring(name(),2) >6)
   ]
    //text()
```